# Calling scala abstract classes with parameters and inner classes from Java

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

If I define a Scala class:

```
 class X(i:Int) {
   println (i)
 }
```

How do I use this class in Java code?

[EDIT] Actually, my problem is slightly more complicated

I have an abstract class

```
 abstract class X(i:Int) {
   println (i)
   def hello(s:String):Unit
 }
```

I need to use this in Java code. Is it possible to do it easily?

[EDIT2] Consider the following code

```
 object B {
    case class C(i:Int)
 }
 abstract class X(i:Int) {
   println (i)
   def hello(a:B.C):Unit
 }
```

In this case, the following java code gives an error in Netbeans IDE but builds fine:

```
 public class Y extends X  {
    public void hello(B.C c) {
       System.out.println("here");
    }
    public Y(int i) {
       super(i);
    }
 }
```

The error I get is:

```
hello(B.C) in Y cannot override hello(B.C) in X; overridden method is static, final
```

Netbeans 6.8, Scala 2.8.

As of now I think the only solution is to ignore the NB errors.

Here is an image showing the exact error(s) I get:
[image: IDE error using scala code from java]

Comment: FYI, this question is very badly written. To start, you did not show an example of what you really were having trouble with -- and given the comment about inner class, you didn't show it even in the edit. Next, you didn't say what you have actually tried to do, and, finally, you didn't explain what errors you were seeing or what you didn't know how to do. Remember: better questions, better and faster answers.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Sorry for that. Actually the error was weird and had me stumped. It seems to be a bug in Netbeans IDE or the Scala plugin, as the code compiles fine, just gives errors in the editor. I am using NB 6.8, Scala 2.8. I have updated my question with the example and error.

Comment: Well, now the question is _very_ good! :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The generated bytecode for your class will be **identical** to the Java definition:

```
abstract class X implements scala.ScalaObject {
  public X(int i) {
    System.out.println(i);
  }

  public abstract void hello(String s);

  //possibly other fields/methods mixed-in from ScalaObject
}
```

Use it exactly as you would for this equivalent Java; subclass and provide a concrete implementation of the `hello` method.

Comment: Actually, it implements `scala.ScalaObject` as well, which means javac needs Scala's library in the class path.

Comment: Yes, it works. The only issue is that Java cannot call inner classes in Scala. So some refactoring was necessary.

Comment: Update the above comment. Refactoring was not necessary as it seems to be a bug in NB. However, after refactoring (moving inner classes outside), the IDE errors went away.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the Scala library jar in the class path to compile any Java code extending a Scala class. For example:

```
dcs@ayanami:~/tmp$ cat X.scala
abstract class X(i:Int) {
   println (i)
   def hello(s:String):Unit
}

dcs@ayanami:~/tmp$ scalac X.scala
dcs@ayanami:~/tmp$ cat Y.java
public class Y extends X {
    public Y(int i) {
        super(i);
    }

    public void hello(String s) {
        System.out.println("Hello "+s);
    }
}
dcs@ayanami:~/tmp$ javac -cp .:/home/dcs/github/scala/dists/latest/lib/scala-library.jar Y.java
```

Comment: It's fair to assume that the OP was already doing this, given that the first example worked :)

Comment: @Kevin Well, he didn't say _what_ wasn't working, now did he?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to call Scala code from Java (maybe with some name mangling and so on). What happens if you try the following?

```
X x = new X(23);
```

In more complicated cases you can use `javap` or similar tools to find out how the Scala code got translated. If nothing else works, you can still write some helper methods on Scala side to make access from Java side easier (e.g. when implicits are involved).

Comment: This works in the first example. However, I am having problem for the second case